# Are there things I can do during a year, before filing my previous year tax return, to reduce previous years taxes

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction

This is about filing the U.S. Federal tax return for the previous year. Are there things a person can do during the first months of the new year, before filing the previous years taxes, to reduce the amount of taxes due for the previous year?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are very few things you can do retroactively. If you're a cash based taxpayer (which almost any individual taxpayer would be), your tax is recognized when the transaction occurs.

However some things can in fact be done. One biggest example is related to tax deferred accounts:

- You can contribute to your IRA up to the tax due date (April 15th, most years) and treat this contribution as if it was made in the prior year.
- You can contribute to your Solo-401(k) similarly.
- You can contribute to your HSA similarly.

Some of these contributions may be deductible and provide tax benefit in the year to which you attributed the contribution.

The reason you can "backdate" those is because of practical reasons: the contributions limits to those depend on your income, health coverage, and types of income during the year - so you can only determine your overall eligibility and limits once the year has ended.

Comment: IRA not if you participated (last year) in employer plan; and HSA only if you had high-deductible coverage, and no other, during last year -- i.e. you can _contribute_ retroactively but you can't become _eligible_ retroactively. However, if you were not HSA-eligible the whole year, but were eligible last December and will remain eligible _all_ of _this_ year (the 'testing period') you can contribute the whole-year amount for _last_ year (and for this year also).

Comment: And one other thing _some_ (not very many) people can do: if you have a child or other dependent that qualifies you for EITC, CTC/ACTC, ODC, or AOTC, and maybe more I forgot, _except_ for not having an SSN or ITIN as applicable, you have until April 15+ to get that SSN or apply for the ITIN (even if it takes them a while to process the ITIN, as it usually(?) does, it's backdated to when the application was received, normally with your filed return).